# Почему растет нагрузка на CPU в Angular приложении?

Tags: angular4

Есть приложение в котором куча так называемых слайдов, в каждом слайде выводится список, в каждом элементе есть три поля, в которых реализованы компоненты, аналогичные селекту, с дополненным функционалом. Вначале все хорошо, но стоит начать выбирать в селекте значения(мультиселект), начинает расти нагрузка на CPU, потом она чуть-чуть спадает, но уже не до того уровня как было раньше. И чем больше изменений делаешь, тем все больше растет нагрузка. В итоге все доходит до того, что вся аппа начинает дико тормозит и загрузка CPU 100%.

P.S: Слайды могут добавляться, удаляться, мержиться, количество айтемов тоже меняется, в общем форма довольно интерактивная и похоже, что при любом изменении модели, начинает расти нагрузка на CPU. Angular 4

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать не имея кода. Однако могу предположить что дело в changesDetection. Т.е. ngZone очень часто делает проверки компонентов на изменения. Попробуйте в компонентах выставить changesDetection в OnPush.